# Sum of Legendre symbols for divisors of a quadratic non-residue modulo an odd prime.

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

Let $\big(\frac{n}{p}\big)=-1$ (Legendre's symbol) for an odd prime p. Then show that
$$\sum_{d,\ \ d\mid n}\Big(\frac{d}{p}\Big)=0.$$
I know that if $d$ is a divisor of $n$, then $-d$ is also its divisor. Therefore, by properties of Legendre's symbol, we have
$$\Big(\frac{-d}{p}\Big)=\Big(\frac{-1}{p}\Big)\times \Big(\frac{d}{p}\Big).$$Since $p$ is an odd prime, we have that $$ \Big(\frac{-1}{p}\Big)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=\pm 1.$$  If $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd, then we can prove. How to deduce the result when $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is even.

Is my way of solving correct? Please give hint or solution.

Comment: Usually, the assumption when computing a sum over divisors, is that you pick only the positive divisors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legendre symbol is a completely multiplicative function whose values are in $\{-1,1,0\}$. Therefore
$$\Big(\frac{d}{p}\Big)\Big(\frac{n/d}{p}\Big)=\Big(\frac{n}{p}\Big)=-1\implies\Big(\frac{d}{p}\Big)=-\Big(\frac{n/d}{p}\Big).$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{d,\ \ d\mid n}\Big(\frac{d}{p}\Big)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{d,\ \ d\mid n}\Big(\frac{d}{p}\Big)+\sum_{d,\ \ d\mid n}\Big(\frac{n/d}{p}\Big)\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d,\ \ d\mid n}\left(\Big(\frac{d}{p}\Big)+\Big(\frac{n/d}{p}\Big)\right)=0$$